# How to integrate exponential and square roots of polynomials?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+x}x^{a-1}e^{-\frac{x\ln x}{2(1-x)}}dx\,,\quad a>0$$
I tried using partial functions but that didn't lead to anything.
Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: [Differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) perhaps?

Comment: Out of interest, what led you to this integral?